# PHP - Accessing variables from different files

Tags: php, mysql, include

I have 3 files in my project. For arguments sake let's called them a.php, b.php and c.php.

In a.php I have a declared variable: `$sql_connection`

In b.php I have declared a function: `check_if_logged_in()`

With these declared, I now want to be able to use the variables across my files. I have included a.php in my b.php file, and I included my b.php inside c.php.

I'd expect this all to work but for some reason b.php isn't getting `$sql_connection` from a.php?

My `a.php` file:

```
<?php

    $sql_connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

?>
```

My `b.php` file:

```
<?php

    include ("a.php");

    function check_if_logged_in() {

        $sqlquery = mysqli_query($sql_connection, ...

    }

?>
```

My `c.php` file:

```
<?php

    include ("b.php");

    check_if_logged_in();

?>
```

Comment: Your files "communicate" properly but you have to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). And **no**, the `global` keyword is not the solution to your problems. It is the cause of other, bigger problems that lurk in the dark, waiting for you to use it.

Comment: and @axiac interesting article! thank you :)

Comment: @axiac I mean by defintion it is an article...if found the answer within the article you provided so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use the variable `$sql_connection` within a function, which is initialised/declared outside; i.e. you have a scope issue!

Read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Solution;

**A.** Pass `$sql_connection` to the function call like this: `check_if_logged_in($sql_connection)`

or

**B.** Use the `global` for e.g.

```
function check_if_logged_in() {
    global $sql_connection;
    $sqlquery = mysqli_query($sql_connection, ...
}
```

P.S. Although option **B** works; it is not recommended as it is considered bad pratise; see [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Comment: Using the `global` keyword is not recommended, and is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that; forgot. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the params.

```
function check_if_logged_in($sql_connection) {
$sqlquery = mysqli_query($sql_connection, ...
```

So

```
check_if_logged_in($sql_connection);
```

Comment: I never said this at the time but you were correct and also deserved the correct answer badge. Thank you for contributing!

Comment: Better late than never ahahah :)